# what does the word "process" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I would like to ask this question to an IRS representative for getting information about whether my application is still in progress or if the process completed without any problem? Is this the right way to say that?

> I filled out an SS-4 form to obtain an EIN and faxed it on [date you sent it]. I would like to know if the application has been processed yet.

Could you please explain the definition of ***process*** in this sentence.

Comment: The verb 'to process' describes what the office does to the application. The sentence asks whether they have finished dealing with it.

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this sentence, processing means "have they finished entering it into their system and verifying that they have all the documents they need from you so they can send it on to the next department for assessment" ( interviews, approval, etc.)